# How can I log the Alexa handler_input object so I can view it in CloudWatch logs using Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to log the handler_input object, so I can view its properties in the CloudWatch logs. However, when I try to log it using `print(handler_input)` I just see this on CloudWatch: `<ask_sdk_core.handler_input.HandlerInput object at 0x7f3850c30be0>` I was hoping to see the entire object that is there, rather than just a description of it!

Below is my logic where we can see the handler_input being printed.

```
class GetNewFactHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Skill Launch and GetNewFact Intent."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return (is_request_type("LaunchRequest")(handler_input) or
                is_intent_name("GetNewFactIntent")(handler_input))

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        logger.info("In GetNewFactHandler")

        print(handler_input)

        # get localization data
        data = handler_input.attributes_manager.request_attributes["_"]

        random_fact = random.choice(data[prompts.FACTS])
        speech = data[prompts.GET_FACT_MESSAGE].format(random_fact)

        handler_input.response_builder.speak(speech).set_card(
            SimpleCard(data[prompts.SKILL_NAME], random_fact))
        return handler_input.response_builder.response
```

How can I log my handler_input so the object properties are readable in CloudWatch?